# Comparing items with each other in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, loops

I have a `List<DiscountRule>` and I need to iterate over these checking to see if any of the rules clash with each other. There are some properties on the rule such as `BrandID` and `CategoryID` which indicate which brand and category the rule applies to along with `Include/Exclude` flags.

A rule would clash if both category and brand match an existing rule if the following example condition occurs:

**Rule 1**

Include brand Include category

**Rule 2**

Exclude brand Exclude category

Obviously a clash can occur if a rule is Include Exclude and Exclude Include and vice versa which I also check for.

I need a way of looping over these and flagging those that are clashing within the list. Here's what I currently have:

```
public bool CheckDiscountRuleClash(DiscountRule other)
{
    if (this.CategoryId == other.CategoryId && this.BrandId == other.BrandId)
    {
        if (this.BrandInclude && this.CategoryInclude
         && !other.BrandInclude && !other.CategoryInclude)
        {
            this.RuleClashes = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if (!this.BrandInclude && !this.CategoryInclude
            && other.BrandInclude && other.CategoryInclude)
        {
            this.RuleClashes = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.BrandInclude && !this.CategoryInclude
            && !other.BrandInclude && other.CategoryInclude)
        {
            this.RuleClashes = true;
            return true;
        }
        else if (!this.BrandInclude && this.CategoryInclude
                && other.BrandInclude && !other.CategoryInclude)
        {
            this.RuleClashes = true;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.RuleClashes = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which I'm calling like:

```
rules.Where(i1 => rules.Any(i2 => i1.CheckDiscountRuleClash(i2))).ToList();
```

But this obviously only gives me back those which satisify the `Any()` condition. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Just curios - is `CheckDiscountRuleClash` simplifies to `var value = this.CategoryId == other.CategoryId && this.BrandId == other.BrandId && this.BrandInclude != other.BrandInclude && this.CategoryInclude != other.CategoryInclude; this.RuleClashes = value; return value;`?

Answer (score 0):

To get back all of the pairs that match your condition simply project each sequence into it's matches:

```
var conflictingRules = rules.SelectMany(rule => 
    rules.Where(other => rule.CheckDiscountRuleClash(other))
    .Select(other=> new { rule, other }));
```

Comment: This will return a pair of conflicting items wont it? Is there a way to return all of the rules (or just have it operate on the reference returning a `void`), and only have the conflicting items flagged as the `CheckDiscountRuleClash()` method does?

Comment: @dtsg If you just want a list of all rules involved in any conflict then that's what you get out of the code that you had to start with already.  This allows you to see which rule(s) it conflicted with.  If that's not what you want then you need to be clear about what you *do* want.

Comment: Working with the pairs would lead to O(N^2) time, which is considered bad.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy If that's the problem that needs to be solved, that's the problem that needs to be solved.  It's only bad to use an O(N^2) algorithm if a superior algorithm can solve the same problem.  Given what the problem is asking for, it's actually *impossible* to solve the problem in a lower asymptotic complexity.

Comment: check out my answer to see how to do it in linear time

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy The size of the output is O(n^2).  Just printing out the already discovered results is an O(n^2) operation.  Your answer also doesn't match the OP's requirements; his requirements are where *all* conditions don't match, not where *none* of the conditions don't match.

Comment: Servy  you are wrong. The outer loop is just iterating the groups and tge inner is just items inside one group. According to the code in original answer not all flags should differ.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy You're code doesn't do as much work *because it doesn't compute the same thing*.  The code *does* in fact demonstrate all of the flags differing.  None of the conditions provided involve both flags being the same.

Comment: Exactly. If every flag is the same the original code assumes there's no clash.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy The code says that there is a clash if both flags are different, thus there isn't a clash if *any* of the flags are the same, not if *all* of the flags are the same.  There are of course ways do do this in far less code, but that's indeed what his code does, and also what his description of what the code should do says.

Comment: @Servy Agree, i was mistaken in this part. Fixed. Still the approach applies, you can check my updated answer and live code on dotnetfiddle it compares with your approach side by side.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Strictly speaking your answer is in fact O(N^2) as well.  As I said, just printing out all of the output in the worse case is O(N^2).  Your solution may be faster, but it's still within the same asymptotic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a foreach loop instead to make sure you go through every item in the list

```
foreach (var rule in rules) // where rules is your List<DiscountRule>
            {
                var result = CheckDiscountRuleClash(rule);
                // do something with the result here (boolean)
                ...
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with Linq join in linear time:

```
var conflictingRules =
            from rule in rules
            join other in rules
            on new{rule.BrandId, rule.CategoryId, rule.BrandInclude, rule.CategoryInclude} equals new{other.BrandId, other.CategoryId, BrandInclude = !other.BrandInclude, CategoryInclude = !other.CategoryInclude}
            select new{rule, other};
```

The idea is to join the list with the the 'counterparts' - the ones known to conflict the other.
Same approach also allows you to use the algorithm with an SQL database if you want.

Note that this algorithm works in linear time, an outperforms the ones iterating all pairs (for example with SelectMany, which is O(N^2)) that the other answers demonstrate, by orders of magnitude, starting from the list of few doesens of brands an categories.

Also note that this code does not use the original CheckDiscountRuleClash code, so it it's smaller by 30 lines of code
.
You can check out the live code with performance comparision here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZtRfcz

Note that if you increase the numbers a bit, the slow method would leed to execution timeout at 5 seconds on dotnetfiddle. Take computation complexity serious!